# Video is not playing in angular 4 but refresh page is working

Tags: angular, html, html5-video

I am using video tag html
But video is not playing when page is loaded then after move another page is working.please give me solution.

```
<video #videoPlayer class="slider-video" width="100%" preload="auto" loop="" muted="muted" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;"
  poster="assets/images/banner.png" src="https://wellfasterstore.blob.core.windows.net/images/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay">
</video>
```

Return Error::
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Comment: any solution you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  `controls` attribute in video tag and remove `autoplay="autoplay"`

```
<video 
    controls 
    #videoPlayer 
    class="slider-video" 
    width="100%" 
    preload="auto" 
    loop="" 
    muted="muted" 
    style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;"
    poster="assets/images/banner.png"
    src="https://wellfasterstore.blob.core.windows.net/images/1.mp4" 
    type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I want play video without any controls in angular4.